# ModuleNotFoundError in regular .py files, but working when run with pytest .py files

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I'm writing a concurrency test where the code opens two separate playwright browsers and run them separately and concurrently. The structure is as follows

```
MoveMouse
    |
     ----__init__.py
     ----MoveMouse.py
UnitTest
    |
     ----__init__.py
     ----TestMoveMouse
            |
             ----__init__.py
             ----test_move_mouse.py
             ----concurrent_browsers.py
```

In both `test_move_mouse.py` and `concurrent_browsers.py` I have

```
import os
import sys
current = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent = os.path.dirname(current)
sys.path.append(parent)
from MoveMouse.MoveMouse import wind_mouse as wm
```

**From the terminal, running `pytest test_move_mouse.py` works but when run with `python concurrent_browsers.py` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MoveMouse'`**.
Here are the files `test_move_mouse.py` and `concurrent_browsers.py`

test_move_mouse.py:

```
import os
import sys
import pytest
from playwright.sync_api import Page, expect, sync_playwright

current = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent = os.path.dirname(current)
sys.path.append(parent)
from MoveMouse.MoveMouse import wind_mouse as wm

def test_drawing_board():
    rel_path = r"/mats/drawing_board.html"
    file_path = "".join([r"file://", os.getcwd(), rel_path])
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        # Fetch drawing board
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=0.5)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.mouse.move(400,50) # Place mouse in a random position in the browser before fetching the page
        page.goto(file_path)

        # Start points
        start_point = 100
        x = 1200

        # Move mouse
        page.mouse.down()
        for y in range(100, 1000, 100):
            # Generate mouse points
            points = []
            wm(start_point, y, x, y, M_0=15, D_0=12, move_mouse=lambda x, y: points.append([x, y]))

            # Draw
            page.mouse.move(start_point, y)
            page.mouse.down()
            for point in points:
                page.mouse.move(point[0], point[1])
            page.mouse.up()
```

concurrent_browsers.py:

```
import os
import sys
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

current = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent = os.path.dirname(current)
sys.path.append(parent)
from MoveMouse.MoveMouse import wind_mouse as wm


def run_drawing_board(mouse_move, start_point):
    rel_path = r"/mats/drawing_board.html"
    file_path = "".join([r"file://", os.getcwd(), rel_path])
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        # Fetch drawing board
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=0.5)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.mouse.move(400, 50)  # Place mouse in a random position in the browser before fetching the page
        page.goto(file_path)

        # Move mouse
        x = 1200
        page.mouse.down()
        for y in range(100, 1000, 100):
            # Generate mouse points
            points = []
            wm(start_point, y, x, y, M_0=15, D_0=12, move_mouse=lambda x, y: points.append([x, y]))

            # Draw
            page.mouse.move(start_point, y)
            page.mouse.down()
            for point in points:
                page.mouse.move(point[0], point[1])
            page.mouse.up()

def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        start_points = [100, 400]
        executor.map(run_drawing_board, start_points)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

**Both have the same above MouseMove import and are in the same directory so why does it work for `test_move_mouse.py` but not `concurrent_browsers.py`?**

Comment: Did you have a ´__init__.py´ file in each module folder?

Comment: Yes I did. I have also modified the code for easier understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to replace

```
current = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent = os.path.dirname(current)
sys.path.append(parent)
```

with

```
current_dir = os.getcwd().split("/")
root_idx = current_dir.index("TheProjectRootFolder")
root_dir = "/".join(current_dir[:root_idx+1])
sys.path.append(root_dir)
```

and everything worked. In the original code I printed out the parent value and found that it was not directing to the root folder `TheProjectRootFolder` but only one above and therefore didn't work for `concurrent_browsers.py`, but for some reason, probably because of pytest, worked for `test_move_mouse.py`. I changed to the latter coding for both files, and they both worked. Hope that helps anyone who encounters the same issue.